# warning on 64bit string formatter in mingw environment

Tags: c, scanf, mingw-w64

What is the correct way to avoid warnings on 64bit printf/scanf arguments on the most recent versions of mingw-w64?

I know that mingw-w64 relies on microsoft runtime for many standard library functions, and that these functions are not compatible with C99 standard.

Old answers say to use **%I64d**, but as the C99 standard is **%lld**, anyway if I compile with **-Wall -pedantic** I get warning for **BOTH** syntax, here is a small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long test;
    scanf("%I64d", &test);
    scanf("%lld", &test);
}
```

Compile it with gcc (my version is mingw-w64 5.0.4, gcc 8.2.0):

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.c -Wall -pedantic
```

It gives the following warnings:

```
dev:tmp dev$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test.exe test.c -Wall -pedantic
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:11: warning: ISO C does not support the ‘I64’ ms_scanf length modifier [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%I64d", &test);
           ^~~~~~~
test.c:6:11: warning: ISO C does not support the ‘I64’ ms_scanf length modifier [-Wformat=]
test.c:7:14: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘l’ in format [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%lld", &test);
              ^
test.c:7:11: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     scanf("%lld", &test);
           ^~~~~~
test.c:7:14: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘l’ in format [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%lld", &test);
              ^
test.c:7:11: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     scanf("%lld", &test);
           ^~~~~~
```

Removing **-Wall** removes both warnings, without **-pedantic** I can compile without warnings line 6 (%I64d) but not line 7 (%lld).

Comment: Please stop tagging unrelated languages, your question is about C. You're using a C compiler to compile a program written in C language.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but you might want search for `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` for a workaround. It might help you (?).

Comment: @user694733 you might be right https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Windows MingW GCC will know it will target a b0rken libc

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compile to Microsoft platform, you *cannot be pedantic* about following the standard. **Embrace, extend (and extinguish)!** Remove the `-pedantic` or get a proper C99/C11/C17 implementation.

---

C89 does not support `%lld`. It seems you need to disable `-Wformat` if you happen to target a library that supports it as an extension.

Comment: Well, aside from the fact that MinGW-w64 does provide a means to provide a conforming C lib through transparent wrappers and some minor additions in their runtime. See e.g. the `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` which does just that for functions like `scanf`.

Comment: @rubenvb Wow, I didn't know about that compiler switch. This is great and also answers the question, you should write it as an answer.

Comment: While I'm always for justified MS bashing, this is not exactly the problem. The modifiers have not been valid before C99 and `-pedantic` seems to check for this version (the documentation is not really clear about this - or missed it). So it's more gcc to blame or OP specified the wrong version of the standard or uses a gcc version <5 without explicit `-std=`.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite no, this is GCC 8.2.0. But MinGW knows the standard library is C89 only, and especially doesn't support `%lld` if the program runs on WinXP.

Comment: ... and it is not as if Microsoft couldn't have "anticipated" %lld or C99 by the time Windows XP came out :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I never worked with MinGW and avoid Windows like hell. But maybe it justg sets the default for gcc to ANSI. Not sure, but maybe there's a config file for gcc (never had to care, as I always tell the compiler explicit).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite so the issue is that by default MinGW will use the msvc runtime :F and it needs to work against it

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The best workaround also fixes all other Windows problems: Use Linux :-). I never understood why preople use Windows for development at all. But that's another discussion.