# Printing long long in C

Tags: c, printf

I'm working on a program that convert strings to integers.
The code works just fine but I got this warning that I can't solve.
I tried to look it up but nothing helpful was found.

Here is the simple code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x[8] = "ABCDWXYZ";
    long long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sum = sum * 100 + (long long)x[i];
    }
    printf("%lli", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the warning I got:

```bash
too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]  //Line 11
unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]  //Line 11
```

Comment: What's your compiler / standard library implementation?

Comment: Post the compiler command that you run.

Comment: Also, different strings will cover to the same integer with your program, as there's actually more possible `char` outside the range (0,99) than inside it.

Comment: By the way what's the purpose of the above code?

Comment: `char x[8] = "ABCDWXYZ"` -> `char x[9] = "ABCDWXYZ"` or even better `char x[] = "ABCDWXYZ"`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't see how will that change anything. anyway I tried it and as expected it multiplied the result *100 once more.

Comment: @alex Compiler and version?

Comment: @SupportUkraine it's mingw v 6.2

Comment: @Alex That version is half decade (2018) old, try using MSYS2 instead

Comment: @Darth-CodeX I'm not allowed to make any changes in the in company's computers

Comment: @Alex, I tried running your above code in mingw 6.2 it DID NOT produced any warning

Comment: @Darth-CodeX Well, Let's just pray it doesn't show up on my boss's computer. :)

Comment: @alex just tell him its computers fault not yours, show him this online compiler https://godbolt.org/z/f4f5bvx4z

Comment: @alex Is your real goal to sort strings (as per comment below)? In that case I fail to see the idea of converting to integers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `char x[8] = "ABCDWXYZ";` is fine as long as `x` isn't used as a string

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201952/warning-on-64bit-string-formatter-in-mingw-environment

Comment: Related https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/

Comment: Also duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70593571/584518  (I won't dupe hammer with my own answers as target since I'm partial)

Answer (score 1):

Compiler, mingw v 6.2, with the compiler options used do not understand the `"ll"`, in `"%lli"`.

Alternatives.

- Compile as C11. [@Haris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992876/printing-long-long-in-c#comment134031081_75992943)
- Use a more up-to-date compiler. (OP implies this is not an option.)
- Re-code and use some crafted helper function to output a 64-bit as decimal text.
- Re-code and use compiler specific formats.  Not reccomendeded.

---

OP's `sum * 100 + (long long)x[i]` is curious.  To read 8 characters of an 8 character array and form all possible 64-bit values, I'd expect `unsigned long long sum`, `sum * (UCHAR_MAX+1) + (unsigned char)x[i]` and `"%llu"`.  That magic number 100 seems strange.  Maybe OP meant `0x100`?

Comment: I don't see why compiling as C11 would make any difference since the problem is non-conformance with C99. This whole thing is a known bug in Mingw + libs and the work-around is `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before including stdio.h.